# Rails SQL Subquery not calculating correct in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a query that has a subquery which performs a calculation. This is part of the subquery:

```
SUM(
            CASE 
            WHEN s.partially_met = false AND s.fully_met = true 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END
        )::float * 100.0 / COUNT(s.outcome_id)::float as fully_met_percent
```

When I run the whole query in development or testing it always returns the correct result. 
When I run the rails active record query which generates the above it always returns the correct result in development and testing.

When I run the SQL directly against my heroku staging database it generates the correct result.

However the Active record query will always return 0.0 for the above on my heroku staging app.

If I run the SQL through the rails console for my heroku staging app using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute it will always return 0.0

Can anyone shed light as to why this is happening or any ideas where to look?

Rails 6.0.0 app, Ruby 2.6.1

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First, maybe your schema on staging if different from development.
Second, maybe your data on staging is different from development.

Comment: Thanks. The schemas match and I’ve done a db dump and checked as well. The weird thing is that the Raw SQL works on the staging database, but not when it’s passed through the rails console with activerecord::Base.connection.execute